# Why image is cutoff when render

Tags: rendering

I have finish my model and when Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to render my image is cutoff from bottom. I tried camera clipping start and end value of 1000

**Original Image**

[image]

Render view

[image]

When Press <kbd>F12</kbd> render view its good

[image]

Applied scale shrink my model

[image]

Any suggestion or help why image is cutting off from below only in render view

Comment: Hidden objects or renderlayer masking?

Comment: @SergeL i never used masking uptill know and i press alt+H to unhide still same result

Comment: That's weird. What does it look like in rendered view (Shift+Z IIRC)?

Comment: @seaturtle i have pressed f12 to render and its render good but shift+z its not

Comment: "Material preview dummy" can be the cause. It is blocking viewport, while tuned off in final render

Comment: @SergeL i turn on same result

Comment: @SergeL http://pasteall.org/pic/index.php?id=120492

Comment: @SergeL what you mean by eye pictograms

Comment: This material dummy - you turned on final render in outliner (camera pictogram), but instead you should turn off viewport display (eye pictogram)

Comment: @SergeL i turn on and off in render and in render view both always the result same

Comment: Well, try to delete every object in scene one by one to see if anything will work out.